# Python REST Service Now API for text search

Tags: python, python-3.x, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am new to external scripting in Service Now.

I have this requirement of performing a text search in Service Now. I'm planning to insert the texts to be searched in a csv file and then through a python rest API of service now, perform the text search.

However, I was unable to find any direct python REST Service Now API to do text search. Does anyone know  any alternative ways of doing this task?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'Global Text Search API' in ServiceNow platform to get search results. First you need to get the list of search groups available and then send a query with list of groups that need to be searched and the search keyword.

Here's a sample program that searched for keyword agent in Knowledge base and Service catalog.

```
import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://<instance>.service-now.com/api/now/v1/globalsearch/groups'

# Eg. User name="admin", Password="admin" for this code sample.
user = 'admin'
pwd = 'admin'

# Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:',response.json())
    exit()

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
data = response.json()
print(data)

url = 'https://<instance>.service-now.com/api/now/v1/globalsearch/search?sysparm_groups=2b77ce594bd6c0d901b8fbe25ceff671&sysparm_search=agent'

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:',response.json())
    exit()

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Comment: what does this mean "sysparm_groups=2b77ce594bd6c0d901b8fbe25ceff67" does this represent the ID of the search group

Comment: Yes, that's the ID of Knowledge base and Service catalog search group. You can find the IDs of different search groups from first query.